# jQuery Checkbox button with no label - Show/Hide UL children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've gotten assistance with two scripts before, and I'm really thankful for that! I'm hoping someone can come to assistance once again.

One script lets me Show/Hide UL children and unselect other parents checkbox.

The second script was for a Checkbox button when no label was present.

Both were jquery solutions. The issue at the moment is that the two scripts are conflicting. I've made a codepen to show the issue.

**Important to note, I can't change the HTML directly, but I do have the ability to use jquery on the page.**

So currently, the checkboxes are gone, you can show and hide the children by selecting the parent category.
But the second script, the one making the checkboxes, seems to override something.
With the first script, show and hide. It's meant to deselect all children if you click the parent category, or any other parent category.

If you disable the **checkbox button with no label** script, then the show hide functionality works as intended. But then I'm left with checkboxes again.

Here's a link to the codepen:

https://codepen.io/mjthehunter/pen/YgaOxr

```
<!-- Hide/Unhide Categories -->
$('.fes-category-checklist > li > label.selectit > input[name^="download_category"]').change(function() {
  var categoryId = this.value;
  var $checkbox = $(this);

  $('.fes-category-checklist')
    .find('li[id^="download_category"]')
    .attr('data-open', function(index, value) {
      return this.id.endsWith(categoryId) && value === 'false';
    });

  $checkbox
    .closest('ul')
    .find('input[name^="download_category"]')
    .not(this)
    .prop('checked', false);
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.fes-category-checklist')
    .find('> li[id^="download_category"]')
    .attr('data-open', false)
    .fadeIn();
});


<!-- checkbox button with no label -->
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.fes-category-checklist, .fes-category-checklist .children').addClass('nolist');

  $('.selectit').addClass('checkbutton');

  $('.checkbutton').click(function(){
    if( $(this).children('input:checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
         $(this).addClass('ischecked');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('ischecked');
    }
  });  

});
```

I really hope someone can help.
Thanks!

Morten

Comment: What is your question? We don't have info on what was done before or not. So can you tell what the current issue you're facing is and what do you expect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your change event for your checkboxes, you are setting all the other checkboxes to not be checked with this code:

```
$checkbox
.closest('ul')
.find('input[name^="download_category"]')
.not(this)
.prop('checked', false);
```

But you are not removing the `ischecked` class that is added with your "checkbox button with no label" script. You will have to remove this also.... like this:

```
$checkbox
.closest('ul')
.find('input[name^="download_category"]')
.not(this)
.prop('checked', false)
.parent().removeClass('ischecked'); // <-- add this to remove isSelected class
```

Here is an updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxVzbG)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much